# How can I use func_get_args() with PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, console

I am working on a command line php file, and I tried to use func_get_args(); but I have got a  warning message:
Called from the global scope - no function context in C:\wamp\www\index.php , and it doesn't work.

Does anybody has an idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: patapizza: code isn'r important in this case, because php 5.3 handle to pass command line args in a  different way . KingCrunch is right.

Comment: PHP5.3 handles the command line arguments in the same way, as at least every 5.x version (and as far as I know every 4.x ;)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for the arguments you pass with the cli call

```
var_dump($argv);
```

`func_get_args()` pulls the arguments given to a function/method (thats what the leading `func` means).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `func_get_args()` inside a function.

Example

```
function yourfunc() {
   //> use it here

}
//> Not here
```

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't work.  I allways got a warning. KingCrunch is right, I have totally forgot the argv....